# Alert Dialog with preferences

Tags: android

I'm doing an app that change the background colors but what I want to do now it's to use alertDialog and my problem it's that when I change the screen it's not saving the last change, it appears the alertDialog again. I'm using this but I don't know if I'm doing correctly... I'm using getPreferences because I need to get my activity default SharedPreferences

```
//        SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
//        int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);
//        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
//        editor.putInt("storedInt", storedPreference);
//        editor.commit();

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Alert Dialog")
        .setMessage("Startup Button Visibility:")
        .setPositiveButton("Hidden", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                if(buttonVisible == true)
                {
                    myLayout2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else
                    myLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hidden was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                // continue with delete
            }
         })

        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                // do nothing
            }
         })

         .setNeutralButton("Visible", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            }
         })

         /**
          * Showing alert dialog
          */

        .show();
```

Comment: what you want exactly? why you first get Hidden and set again after that without any change?

Comment: I have already done an app which changes the background color after you pressed a button, and with a click on the screen can also appear and disappear the buttons, and now I'm using alertDialog which will start the mode (visible, hidden buttons or cancel) but my problem comes after I have pressed for instance: Hidden , it works but then if I change the orientation the alertDialog comes again :/

Comment: If you change the orientation of your device you are recreating your activity again. You can use a variable to say if the dialog has ended the way you wanted and saving that variable using `onsaveInstanceState` and recovering it in your `onRestoreInstance` or `onCreate` using your `Bundle` class, if your variable has been defined in the `Bundle` with the value you previously defined, then you wont show the dialog.

Comment: Have you looked into `DialogFragment`s? That's the way to use dialog boxes. It's a little bit more work for building the dialog, but saves you some trouble for layout changes. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment on your question. It looks like you want to retain the state of your activity even though you change it's orientation. Add this to your manifest inside the activity bracket.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Changing the orientation recreates the activity.

Comment: Yeah , that's what I want to do but I need to use onSaveInstance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this when you change an orientation onCreate() is called every time but you can avoid the re-creation of Activity by adding configChanges attribute of Activity in your AndroidManifest file in the activity tag.

android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Answer (score 0):

when you change the orient of screen following event has been occurred.

=== Orientation Change ===

onSaveInstanceState -> onPause -> onStop -> onCreate -> onStart -> onRestoreInstanceState -> onResume.

so when you want save state you can use `onSaveInstanceState()`. and Usually you restore your state in `onCreate()`.

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle icicle) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(icicle);
  icicle.putString("param", value);
}
```

and for restoring that:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
  if (icicle != null){
    value = icicle.getString("param");
  }
}
```

so you can save Color value or anything that you want and restore that in `onCreate()` and set to you `AlertDialog`.

Comment: what is the problem? did you see any Error?

Comment: nope, no error, just when I change the orientation the alertdialog comes again, that's my problem.

Comment: what you want when change the orient?

Comment: after I have choosed an option for instance: hidden buttons, then if I change the orientation it supposes that don't have to appear again the alertdialog, this window has to appear just when I start the app and everytime I rotate it's showing up this window

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44706/discussion-between-shayan-pourvatan-and-jaimito)